# Poisson distribution as a naïve method to estimate probability of infection

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let us suppose that we want to estimate, during a pandemic, the probability of having met an infected person after a walk. Could the cumulative of the Poisson (for $k\geq1$ occurrences) distribution with $\lambda = np$ ($n$ number of people met, $p$ probability for each one to be infected) and $p$ as parameters be suitable to our aim?

Comment: Suitability here depends on intention. A thinned Poisson process as you described is certainly a reasonable (perhaps naïve) theoretic model for such phenomena but whether it is empirically reasonable too is another manner. In other words, as a toy model it is certainly suitable, as a model to inform public health policy, it would require empirical validation and additional scrutiny.

Comment: I agree, I think that in such a model the main problem can be estimate $p$, which depends on too many factors (e.g. the geographical area, whether the population tend to wear masks and so on). Thus one who decides to rely on this model will end to estimate the probability mainly on his prejudice rather than objective observations.